# Visual Studio 2010: prerequisites issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

On Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 I would like to create a installer for a solution I created.

I created it by menu way (File > New project... > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Visual Studio Installer > Setup Project),  added files to their correct destinations etc., and all works fine, except for prerequisites...

The problem is that my solution depends on .Net 3.5 and I would like to install it automatically together with the installer, in some offline way - no internet downloads on installation time.

If on installer project properties I mark "create setup to install install prerequisite components" and mark "download prerequisites from the same location as my application"...

[image: screenshot]

... when I try to run, it shows messages like that:

> Error 7   The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\aspnet.msp' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information. D:\Projetos\Eletronica\M013-Moura\HG-V6-release1\VidaCiclada-semTemperatura\VidaCiclada_Installer\VidaCiclada_Installer.vdproj  VidaCiclada_Installer

Well, I put my offline installer of .Net 3.5 on the same folder EXE output of my solution is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could not completely finished my installer package, I found the issue:

1. I clicked on properties panel
2. I clicked on the setup project
3. On property named "Localization", I changed the value to "English (United States)"

So I could build the project and execute the installer normally (except for SQL Server Express, that I would like to install with that package too, but although it is executed with setup, it does not create the Windows services for it...).

I.e., the issue was that my VS2010 doesn't have the files needed for the setup on my native language, "Portuguese (Brazil)", but it has for English language. The final setup will install prerequisites on English language...